# LWJGL - How do I set (0, 0) to the top left?

Tags: java, coordinates, lwjgl, coordinate-systems

I have noticed that in LWJGL the (0, 0) coordinate is in the bottom left. I am used to and find it much more logical when (0, 0) is on the top left. I was wondering if it was possible to make (0, 0) become the top left of the screen.

Yes I do understand that OpenGL's default (0, 0) is the bottom left, but I was hoping there was a way around this.

Thanks in advance,
ixenocider

Comment: I'd strongly recommend that you find a way to become comfortable doing things the OpenGL way - otherwise your code will be tricky and misleading when seen by others, and you will be training yourself wrongly! Give it some time and get used to the coordinate space :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

Where you usually put this:

```
GL11.glOrtho(0, screenWidth, 0, screenHeight, 1, -1);
```

use this:

```
GL11.glOrtho(0, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, 1, -1);
```

Comment: I have something like this in my own project ``GL11.glOrtho(0.0, videoMode.width(), videoMode.height(), 0.0, -1.0, 1.0);``